# If $p=x^2-6y^2$ is a prime then $p\equiv 1 , 19 \mod{24}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p > 3$ be a prime for which there exists $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p = x^2 - 6y^2$.

Show that $p \equiv 1 \ or \ 19 \mod{24}$.

---

The fact that $p = x^2 - 6y^2$ implies that $\left(\frac{6}{p}\right) = 1$ (Legendre symbol) and therefore $p \equiv 1, 5, 19, 23 \bmod{24}$, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that $p \equiv 1,5,19,23 \pmod{24}$ are your only options you can exclude 5 and 23 by looking at the equation modulo 3. Since $3 \nmid x$ you have $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3$ and thus $p \equiv x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: first, welcome to the site and second, thank you very much (obviously i didn't thought about the question through) :-)

Comment: To be honest, I don't see why $p \equiv 1,5,19,23 \pmod{24}$ are the only options though.

Comment: $p=x^2-6y^2$ therefor $x^2 \equiv 6y^2 \mod(p)$ therefor $( \frac{6y^2}{p}) = ( \frac{6}{p}) ( \frac{y^2}{p}) = ( \frac{6}{p}) = 1$ (i'm refering to Legendre symbol) and it's known that $( \frac{6}{p}) = 1 \iff p \equiv 1,5,19,23 \mod{24}$

Comment: i hope that's more clear now

Comment: Just to flesh out the "it's known that" part of the reasoning: $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=\pm1$, so $\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1$, so $\left(\frac{24}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)\left(\frac{6}{p}\right)=1$. The numbers whose squares are $1 \mod{24}$ are $\pm1,\pm5$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do we have $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = 1$ iff $p \equiv b \pmod a$, where $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod a$? I'm not sure that is true.

Comment: I would use the following argumentation for $\left(\frac 6 p\right) = 1 \Leftrightarrow p \equiv \pm 1, \pm 5 \pmod{24}$:
Since $\left(\frac 6 p\right) = \left(\frac 2 p\right) \left(\frac 3 p\right)$ either both factors are $1$ or $-1$. By Quadratic reciprocity:
$\left(\frac 2 p\right) = 1$ iff $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$, $\left(\frac 2 p\right) = -1$ iff $p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod{8}$, $\left(\frac 3 p\right) = 1$ iff $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{12}$, $\left(\frac 3 p\right) = -1$ iff $p \equiv \pm 5 \pmod{12}$. This yields exactly the possibilities from above.